# Quartz composer view in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode5, quartz-composer

Could anyone get to put a QCview in Xcode 5 ?

Creating a simple Cocoa App with a QC view in main window reports error although I've aded the Frameworks.

I've linked a .zip of the App here: [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1f30yn2yvqegdox/Testapp.zip)

Report is

```
    CompileXIB Testapp/Base.lproj/MainMenu.xib
    cd /Users/Maxime/Desktop/Testapp
    setenv XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --minimum-deployment-target 10.8 --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/Maxime/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testapp-hjzpidyolnahdtgvvkqyvmnhxmtw/Build/Products/Debug/Testapp.app/Contents/Resources/Base.lproj/MainMenu.nib /Users/Maxime/Desktop/Testapp/Testapp/Base.lproj/MainMenu.xib

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

The [Xcode 5 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/xc5_release_notes/xc5_release_notes.html) list this as a known issue:

> Xib files containing an instance of QCView from Quartz Composer fail to build, and cannot be processed by ibtool. Replace the instance of QCView on the canvas with an instance of custom view from the library and set its custom class to “QCView” in the identity inspector.

In Xcode 5.1, if I follow those instructions, it compiles successfully.

Comment: It compiles for me too, but I cannot get the QC Composition to appear. Some more detail on the solution would be really useful as simply replacing QCView object with a Custom View doesn't solve the issue AFAIK. It may be complicated because I pass key values from my XCode app into the composition. Any help advice on how to do this?